# Subversion: How to add a directory which is currently ignored and exists in most working copies?

Tags: svn, ignore

How do you add a directory in subversion which is currently ignored. It is known that the directory exists in most working copies. When you remove it from svn:ignore and add it with svn add, users will get this message on update:

```
An unversioned directory of the same name already exists
```

The goal would be to avoid the message and simply merge the existing directory with the contents from the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `svn up --force <dirname>` will update the directory even if it already exists.

Comment: given the tmie passed, i assume there is no better solution. Accepting your answer :)